# Trying to save base64 (image) file to server, it's empty

Tags: php, ajax, canvas, png

I'm trying to save a canvas image to a folder in my server however the file is empty upon inspection. I'm using AJAX to pass the encoded data to my php script, and then the php script is saving it to the server, empty.

This is the code I have:

JS/AJAX:

```
function convertCanvasToImage(thecanvas) {
                var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
                ajax.open("POST",'testSave.php',false);
                ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');
                ajax.send(canvasData);
            }
```

PHP (testSave.php):

```
    $imageData=$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];

    $filteredData=substr($imageData, strpos($imageData, ",")+1);

    $unencodedData= base64_decode($filteredData);

    //echo "unencodedData".$unencodedData;

    $fp = fopen( 'test.png', 'wb' );
    fwrite( $fp, $unencodedData);
    fclose( $fp );
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: did you check if `$imageData` actually has any content, before padding it through the substr/base64 stuff? just because you get an empty file in php doesn't mean it's php's fault. After all, your ajax call uses `canvasdata`, but nowhere have you defined that in your code snippet, so you could be sending a javascript null/undefined.

Comment: When `HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` isn't populated (depends on php.ini setting), then read from the virtual filename `php://input`.

Comment: Try reading the data from `php://input` i.e. `$imageData = file_get_contents("php://input");`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a line in your function to convert the `<canvas>` to data using the `.toDataURL()` function.

```js
function convertCanvasToImage( thecanvas ) {
    var canvasData = thecanvas.toDataURL( 'image/png' ), //add this
        ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open( 'POST', 'testSave.php', false );
    ajax.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/upload' );
    ajax.send( canvasData );
};

var thecanvas = document.getElementById( 'canvasId' );
convertCanvasToImage( thecanvas );
```

Comment: @themis I updated to make it more clear. It's a DOM canvas object.